# Unable to download extensions in TFS 2017 due to Azure DevOps

Tags: tfs

We have recently started using Azure Devops and due to its login, I am now unable to download extension in TFS 2017. Also if i download the vsix file for extension and try to upload and install it manually then it gives me a warning at legacy extensions page and then error upon upload.
Warning: This extensibility model is deprecated. Learn about the new model for building extensions for Team Foundation Server.
Extension manifest file format is invalid. 
please advise.

Comment: What do you mean "due to its login"? If you're using Azure DevOps, why are you still using on-prem TFS? You need to update your question to include more context. You can install extensions through the marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

**Legacy extension** is different from normal extension, please first check which kind of extension you want to use/install.

For normal extension in Marketplace. Instead of download and upload, you could also directly install and get extension from Marketplace.

1. Open your Azure DevOps Server home page `(https://{server}:DefaultCollection)`.
2. Open the extensions menu and choose Browse Marketplace.

[image]
  3. Select the project collection where you want to install this extension and choose Install.

[image]

And that you could also install Azure DevOps Server extensions from the local gallery.

Besides, for packaged or download `.vsix` file, you could upload them through **Manage extensions**--**Upload Extensions**.

[image]

More details please take a look at this official link--[**Install extensions for on-premises servers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions?view=azure-devops-2019&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops)

**Note:** You must be a Project Collection Administrator and have Edit collection-level information permissions.

---

For legacy extension, it's totally a different thing. If you are using this kind of extension, kindly refer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/838312/a-way-to-manually-upload-new-extensions-into-tfs-2017-u1).

If you still get similar error after following above step. Please also check your TFS version are supported with that extension or not.

Hope it's clearly.